# Data from props not showing in v-model (VueJS)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props, vue-data

I'm trying to use a props from the parent component to use it as a data in my child component.

parent component :

```
 <ChangeCommentModal :comment="this.modalInfo.comment" />
```

And child component (ChangeCommentModal) :

```
props: ['comment'],
data() {
  return {
    localComment: this.comment,
  };
}
```

The localComment variable get the value but I can't use it in a v-model in this child component :

```
<textarea id="message" rows="2" v-model="localComment"></textarea>
```

The textarea is empty when the component is displayed.

Any idea ? Thanks !

Comment: Seems fine to me. Could some other code not mentioned be affecting it?

Comment: Yes I looked at the documentation it this is what they are doing. One thing I didn't mentionned is that this component is a Modal that shows up when you click on a button. The data are passed with a $root.$emit to the parent component but all the props are fine.  When I update my code (it's with npm run serve) sometimes the values shows up

Comment: When I'm directly modifying the props, everything works fine but I get the warning message "Avoid mutating a prop directly..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your code is only assign `this.comment` to `localComment` once when the child component is init. Instead, you can use watcher to watch the change of prop `comment` and assign it to the `localComment` everytime you update from the parent component. Let's try to see if resolve your problem

```
watch() {
   comment(value) {
      this.localComment = value
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh ok I see ! Yes it's perfectly working, Thanks !